# Vim open a file found through grep

Tags: bash, vim, grep

So I'm browsing a file in vim. I realize the function I am looking for is another file. So I do  `:! ack-grep "function tracking" ../` to look for it, and I see I need to examine file "../../tracking/api/ etc etc" some really long file name. what I'm doing now is trying to remember this file, type `fg` to get back into vim, and then :e "that really long file name". I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do this?

For instance, can I do something like `vim -addtab <some file>` from the command line once I've used ack-grep to find what I'm looking for, and then when I do `fg` to get back to vim, the file will be open in one a tab?

Awesome, lots of suggestions. I'll try them all out and in comments as I do. Then I'll pick what worked best for me once I've tried them all.

So this is the function that I settled on:

```
function! s:NewTabGrep(...)
  let args=split(a:1)
  if len(args) == 2
      let dir=args[1]
  else
      let dir='.'
  endif
  echom args[0] . "  " . shellescape(dir)
  tabnew | execute "r ! ack-grep ". shellescape(args[0]) ." ". shellescape(dir) 
endfunction
com! -nargs=? GrepTab call s:NewTabGrep('<args>')
```

This performs the search, and opens the results in a new vim tab. Then I can use CtrlP to open whichever file seems most interesting. Thanks to Merlin2011 for inspiration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `:r ! ack-grep "function tracking" ../` to pull the output directly into the `vim` buffer, and then use `gf` to navigate to the file under the cursor.

If you want to open the file in a new tab instead, you can do `Control-W, gf` in normal mode.

**Update**: If you want the output of the command to appear in a new tab, you can do the following, which opens a new tab, and then immediately pulls the output of the command into it.

```
:tabnew | r!ack-grep "function tracking" ../
```

Comment: Very cool, is it possible to write this to an entirely new file, open in another tab, instead of into the current file?

Comment: ok that works. However, when I try and add that to my .vimrc file, it actually executes the ack-grep and sticks that data into the current buffer. Here's what I added to my .vimrc:  `nnoremap <leader>f :tabnew | r ! ack-grep` Hoping that I could abbreviate it and save myself some typing

Comment: @Trevor, Wrap it inside a function and map the function instead.

Comment: @Trevor, Please update your question. what you have in the comment is very hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

`:vimgrep`  does this by default!  it's the best!  in fact, it's so cool, that you can even use `:vim` to invoke it hahaha

e.g. search all python files for "function tracking"  (works best if you keep your vim working directory in your source code's root folder)

```
:vim /function tracking/ **/*.py
```

^ this will go to the first search result, and then open the [quickfix](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html) window with a list of search results.   I use a binding like `` nmap <silent> \` :QFix<CR> `` to quickly toggle it open and off.  See... http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Toggle_to_open_or_close_the_quickfix_window

--

however, there's a *better* way for navigating to the function:  using `CTRL-]` which **does an instant jump** to the definition!  Combined with `CTRL-O` and `CTRL-I` (jump backwards/forwards), you have an unstoppable move-around files-efficiently combo which will make you forget why you ever used IDE's  =D

I googled this wiki page:  http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags.   One other thing  you have to do is download [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)  and build a tags file in your working directory:  `ctags -R` ...then you're all set!  (note that on Macs/BSD, it has its own ctags which wont work, you gotta use the exuberant one)

Comment: This looked promising. But I tried using the ctags you linked and it gave me a 24 gig tags file! The repo I'm looking at is only 8 or 9 gigs so I don't want to spend that much space on just the tags. Also the QFix is apparently not built in on my version of vim, do I need to install it from somewhere?

Comment: oh geez hahaha!  perhaps your repository is SVN or something and you're also including tags n' branches, in that case maybe change your working directory to just trunk

Comment: ohhhh your vim must not have +quickfix compiled into it.  You can find out by typing :version and scanning that output.  For instance, mine is a "Huge version with MacVim GUI."!  I think it's by default on, so  if you install the package with the "full" version of Vim on most distros it'll have it ^^

Comment: Strange, version reports +quickfix... I'm using git, but I think I have a bunch of other crap in my repo like minified javascript files, so its possible all that bloat caused problems. I might try it again but limit it to only php files or something

Comment: oh oops haha, I actually got the :QFix thing from here  http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Toggle_to_open_or_close_the_quickfix_window   ...and ommited that vital piece of information :D

Answer (score 1):

Vim has the `:grep` command that runs `grep` and stores the results into the quickfix list(you can also use `:lgrep` to load them to the location list). `:grep` also jumps to the first result, but if you don't want that you can use `:grep!` to just load the results to the quickfix list.

Once the results are loaded, you can use `:copen` to open the quickfix list(or `:lopen` to open the location list) and navigate between the results, or use `:cfirst`, `:cnext`, `:cprevious` and `:clast`(or `:lnext`, `:lfirst`, `:lprevious` and `:llast`) for navigation.

So, if you want to open the result in a new file, you have three options:

1. `:grep! "function tracking" ../**/*`, `:copen` to open the quickfix list, put cursor on the first result, `ctrl-W` Enter to open the result in a new window, `ctrl-W` `T` to move the window to a new tab.
2. `:grep! "function tracking" ../**/*`, `:tabnew` to open a new tab, `:cfirst` to jump to first result.
3. `:tabnew` to open a new tab, `:grep "function tracking" ../**/*` to perform the search and open the first result automatically.

You might find it easier to just use the quickfix list for navigation instead of opening new tabs.

`:grep` uses `grep` by default, but you can set the `grepprg` option to make it use `ack-grep` instead(you might also need to set `grepformat` to recognize the output). You can also use `:vimgrep` to do a search with Vim's regular expression without using an external program, but it will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
:exec 'tab split '.fnameescape(system('ack-grep "function tracking" ../'))
```

should do the trick. (Make it into a function!)

Comment: This opened a blank file in a new tab... I'm somewhat new to vim, can you give a more detailed explanation of what these commands are doing?

Comment: @Trevor: `exec` executes a string as a Vim command. `.` concatenates strings. `fnameescape` escapes file names. `system` is like `!`, but takes and returns a string (it’s a function). Does the new tab have a name? If it’s multiple files, that would do it; this only works for one. `ack-grep` not acting like `grep -l` would also do the trick (I don’t know what `ack-grep` is).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the [ack plugin.](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim), Note that if you have [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) installed, you can search with `ack.vim` asynchronously(You need to write: `let g:ack_use_dispatch=1` in your vimrc file). Also I recommend [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) to replace `ack` since it's really fast.